# Hibernate mapping list inside list

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have 2 tables email_address and group_email

[image]

[image]

I want to get a list of email addresses and if it is group also list the emails of group. Here is my hibernate dom object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email_address")
public class EmailAddressDom {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "email_address_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "email_address_id_seq", sequenceName = "email_address_id_seq")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "is_group")
private boolean isGroup;

@Column(name = "status")
private boolean status;
// Getters and setters
```

And here is the implementation how I am getting the list

```
public List<EmailAddressDom> getEmailAddresses() {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EmailAddressDom.class);
    List<EmailAddressDom> emailAddresses = criteria.list();
    return emailAddresses;
}
```

And the result is

```
[
  {
    "id": 451,
    "name": "HS",
    "isGroup": true,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 452,
    "name": "test4",
    "email": "test4@mail.com",
    "isGroup": false,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 450,
    "name": "test3",
    "email": "test3@mail.com",
    "isGroup": false,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 402,
    "name": "test2",
    "email": "test2@mail.com",
    "isGroup": false,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 401,
    "name": "test1",
    "email": "test1@mail.com",
    "isGroup": false,
    "status": true
  }
]
```

I want to get result like this

```
[
   {
      "id":451,
      "name":"HS",
      "isGroup":true,
      "status":true,
      "groupEmails":[
         {
            "id":450,
            "name":"test3",
            "email":"test3@mail.com",
            "isGroup":false,
            "status":true
         },
         {
            "id":452,
            "name":"test4",
            "email":"test4@mail.com",
            "isGroup":false,
            "status":true
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":402,
      "name":"test2",
      "email":"test2@mail.com",
      "isGroup":false,
      "status":true
   }
]
```

Which mapping should I use in EmailAddressDom entity?

**Updated accordingly to comments**

I have written a simple application mapping following way and it is working fine

```
@ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="group_email",
       joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id")},
       inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="email_addr_id")})
private List<EmailAddressDom> groupEmails;
```

But I have confused setting it in my web application, it throws following exception:

```
Association has already been visited: AssociationKey(table=group_email, columns={email_addr_id})
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: That DB structure is quite horrible...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve self join, in your `EmailAddressDom` class add reference to itself like:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_email", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email_addr_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id" ))
    private List<EmailAddressDom> emailAddressDoms;
```

In `group_email` table you do not require `id` column as  `email_addr_id` and `group_id` combination would be unique or do you allow same email more than once in a group?

**Update after comment from OP**:
To group by email groups, change the mapping like shown below.

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_email", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id" ),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "email_addr_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<EmailAddressDom> emailAddressDoms;
```

Comment: Email address can be in a group  once

Comment: Then you do not require the id column in the group_email table.

Comment: Thank you Rohit for your response. I tried, but I get the following result:
[
  {
    "id": 451,
    "name": "HS",
    "isGroup": true,
    "status": true,
    "groupEmails": []
  },
  {
    "id": 452,
    "name": "test4",
    "email": "test4@mail.com",
    "isGroup": false,
    "status": true,
    "groupEmails": [
      {
        "id": 451,
        "name": "HS",
        "isGroup": true,
        "status": true,
        "groupEmails": []
      }
    ]
  },
 .........
]

Comment: Here is query:
select *
from email_address this_ left outer join group_email groupemail2_ on this_.id=groupemail2_.email_addr_id 
 left outer join email_address emailaddre3_ on groupemail2_.group_id=emailaddre3_.id 

but it should be as follows:
select *
from email_address this_ left outer join group_email groupemail2_ on this_.id=groupemail2_.group_id
 left outer join email_address emailaddre3_ on groupemail2_.email_addr_id =emailaddre3_.id

Comment: Could you add it as update to your question? It difficult to read here.

Comment: I changed mapping as follows:
  @JoinTable(name = "group_email", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),      
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="email_addr_id", referencedColumnName="id" ))
But it throws following error:
The association has already been visitd: AssociationKey (table=group_email, columns= {email_addr_id})

Comment: What you want is `@ManytoOne` and not `@OnetoMany`. Could you try with manytoone with the changed join table in comment above?

Answer (score 0):

Either Do Eager loading

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_email", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email_addr_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id" ))
    private List<EmailAddressDom> emailAddressDoms;
```

OR

//explicitly join in criteria

```
public List<EmailAddressDom> getEmailAddresses() {
Session session = getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EmailAddressDom.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("emailAddressDoms", fetchMode.JOIN);
List<EmailAddressDom> emailAddresses = criteria.list();
return emailAddresses;
```

}